# Service worker fallback takes over React SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, serverside-javascript

On online mode, the service worker api fallback takes over the server side rendered page. When I first load the `/about` page for example, looking in the source code I have the home page rendered (because I defined `/` as `navigateFallback` in the `sw-precache` options):

[image]

I want this behavior only when I'm running on offline mode.

Here are the options I use:

```js
{
  cacheId: pkg.name,
  dontCacheBustUrlsMatching: /./,
  dynamicUrlToDependencies: {
    '/': [ resolve(__dirname, '../server/views/index.ejs') ]
  },
  navigateFallback: '/',
  staticFileGlobs: [
    `${publicDir}/{bundle,vendor}.*.{js,css,gz}`,
    `${publicDir}/manifest.json`
  ],
  stripPrefix: publicDir,
  runtimeCaching: [{
    urlPattern: /api/,
    handler: 'networkFirst'
  }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The expected use case of `navigateFallback` in `sw-precache` is to provide a static HTML document that could be served using a cache-first strategy immediately, without having to go against the network. This ensures that requests for any URL on your site can be fulfilled with something almost instantly, instead of having to wait an indeterminate amount of time for a response from the network. This presupposes that you have a generic HTML page (referred to as an App Shell) that could be used to fulfill any navigation requests, and which knows how to implement client-side logic to examine the current URL and dynamically insert the appropriate content. If you already have code that supports Single Page App-style navigations, then that's usually sufficient.

You can [read more about this architectural pattern](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell), and there's also a [full example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/tree/master/app-shell-demo) of a React-based PWA that uses SSR for the initial navigation (or for clients that don't support service workers) and then upgrades to the `navigateFallback` behavior once the SW work is installed.

If you'd prefer not to use this model, and instead want to always go against the network for your SSR version of each page, and only use a cached page when the network request fails, then the `navigateFallback` option is not the right choice. You can find some [examples](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/custom-offline-page/) of offline fallbacks around the web.

Comment: I'm going to add some clarity to the `sw-precache` docs: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues/310